# SpeedFan not detecting fans

Tags: motherboard, fan, cooling, speedfan

SpeedFan 4.52 is not detecting any of my system fans. Am I doing something wrong? Is my motherboard not supported?
Motherboard: https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170-Gaming-K3-rev-10#ov
Fans: https://www.bequiet.com/en/casefans/616
The fans are connected to a motherboard's SYS_FAN1 and SYS_FAN2 4-pin headers.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

(You seem to be pursuing this question on [various websites](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/963226-speedfan-not-detecting-fans/?tab=comments#comment-11672308).)

In general, your motherboard is problematic to both Speedfan and
[SIV](http://rh-software.com/) ([example link](http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view.php?id=2468)).

I would suggest first to check that you are running the latest
[BIOS version](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170-Gaming-K3-rev-10#support-dl-bios),
which is currently version F23f released on 2018/03/09.
If you wish to update, ensure first that you have backups for everything.

Check to see that your fans are visible in the BIOS.
If not, then it is unlikely that Speedfan can do any better.

Latest versions of Speedfan support the new
[Advanced Fan Control](http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5).
You might give this a try to see if it can help.
Try also SIV to see if it does any better in detecting the fans.

I remark that your motherboard is not listed as being able to change fan speeds
([link to list](http://www.almico.com/forummotherboards.php?man=264)).
If you ever manage to make this work, you might consider adding yours to the list.

Comment: Yeah, I'm really stuck. My main goal is to link sys fans to cpu temperature. I've tried looking for the settings in BIOS, but the setting "Fan Control Use Temperature Input" is missing. SIV software is also missing "select temperature sensor" setting. So I'm just trying to figure out other ways to link the fans to cpu. I'm on the latest BIOS version.

Comment: I can control the speed of the fans both in BIOS and in SIV, but the fans are locked to some motherboard sensor and I can't change it.

Comment: Try to [disable fast boot](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-turn-off-fast-startup-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Why would that change anything?

Comment: There are reports on same motherboard that it helps.

Comment: I think I'm just missing a major feature on my motherboard. I've compared z170 and z270 manual and found that the z270 has the temperature input setting and my motherboard doesn't. I've opened a ticket in gigabyte support see what they have to say, because nobody has an idea how I can link my fans to cpu.

Comment: Well, if you have the wrong board then we can't help.

Comment: I think I've just discovered the best thing ever: https://i.imgur.com/8uhnkr6.png

Comment: This proves that the fans are discoverable. With this information you might be able to use the Advanced Fan Control of Speedfan to add then into the list. If this doesn't work, then your only remaining action is to ask for improvement on the Speedfan forums.

Comment: The fans are discoverable, but not by SpeedFan, I've tried every setting, it just doesn't work, Argus Monitor on the other hand is an amazing software.

Comment: Since your question was about Speedfan, then all I can finally recommend is trying Advanced Fan Control or the Speedfan forums. Argus Monitor may solve the problem, but unfortunately it's not freeware.

Comment: You only need to buy Argus monitor if you want updates, otherwise it's free.